# Assistance w/ SUMIF (HELP)

Tags: microsoft-excel

I'm currently using the following formula to populate the sum of specific data within a sheet:

=SUM(SUMIF(D:D,{"70000","71000","72000","73000","75000"},F:F))

However, I am in search of an addition to this formula. I have a duration column(F) in which there is a range of minutes. Each code ("70000","71000","72000","73000","75000") has a maximum value that can be counted prior to the formula summing. They are as follows:

70000: not greater than 30

71000: not greater than 60

72000: not greater than 30

73000: not greater than 60

75000: not greater than 15

Please let me know if you are aware of a formula that allows this.

Thank you for your assistance!

Comment: now, I feel we are doing your homework  Try modifying the formulas from your last two questions.  This will be similar to the first question.

Comment: Not my homework. Personal work project I took on.

Comment: Too many arguments for this function. Any ideas?=SUM(IF(((D3:D1000=70000)+(D3:D1000=71000)+(D3:D1000=72000)+(D3:D1000=73000)+(D3:D1000=75000))>0,IF(F3:F1000=70000>30,30,F3:F1000),IF(F3:F1000=71000>60,60,F3:F1000),IF(F3:F1000=72000>30,30,F3:F1000),IF(F3:F1000=73000>60,60,F3:F1000),IF(F3:F1000=75000>15,15,F3:F1000)))

Comment: Group the ones which have the same ceiling into their own IF()s, wrap all three IF()s in the SUM() separated by `,`.

Comment: What am I doing wrong?:  =SUM(IF(((D3:D1000=70000,71000,72000,73000,75000)))>0,IF(F3:F1000=70000,72000>30,30,F3:F1000),IF(F3:F1000=71000,73000>60,60,F3:F1000),IF(F3:F1000=75000>15,15,F3:F1000)))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to use this array formula

```
=SUM(IF(((D1:D100=70000)+(D1:D100=72000))>0,IF(F1:F100>30,30,F1:F100),IF(((D1:D100=71000)+(D1:D100=73000))>0,IF(F1:F100>60,60,F1:F100),IF((D1:D100=75000),IF(F1:F100>15,15,F1:F100)))))
```

Being an array formula it needs to be confirmed with Ctrl-Shift-Enter instead of Enter when exiting edit mode.  If done correctly then Excel will put `{}` around the formula.

Also note that the references are no longer full column and should be set to the extents of the data set to avoid unnecessary calculations.